# Bluetooth: GATT service UUID for sending string to printer from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

I am trying to send string to my bluetooth printer via `navigator.bluetooth`. It requires the `UUID` for the service and characteristic.

What is the generic `UUID` for the service and characteristic for sending string?

```
let services = await selectedDevice.gatt.getPrimaryService(whatUUID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of bluetooth UUID: [16-bit UUID Numbers
Document](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf).

Use bluetooth internals, chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices, to inspect which services a device supports.